# Print json in python

Tags: python, json, facebook, api

I want to print

```
for post in data["data"]:

  print post["message"]
```

However i managed to ran only this
Maybe it because the message has two lines?

```
**for post in data["data"]:

  print post["link"]**
```

Why?

Thanks in advance

```js
{
   "data": [
      {
         "message": "Have you checked out our SPOOKY SALE yet?\nWith X2 your Coin Store Bonus and all the surprises waiting for you, it is THE way to celebrate Halloween!\nSo go ahead, don\u2019t let the black cat get our tongue\u2026 pick up these \ud83d\udc31 FREE COINS \ud83d\udc31 htUNGAW and see what it\u2019s all about!\n~Lucy",
         "link": "h760.128874350565152/1165459096906667/?type=3",
         "permalink_url": "h/1165459096906667:0",
         "created_time": "2016-10-31T12:56:01+0000",
         "type": "photo",
         "name": "Timeline Photos",
         "id": "128874350565152_1165459096906667",
         "shares": {
            "count": 61
         },
         "reactions": {
            "data": [
               
            ],
            "summary": {
               "total_count": 1257,
               "viewer_reaction": "NONE"
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm asking how can i print the message, it gives me the error that the "message" isn't in the dictionary                                                                                  print "message" in data["data"]     output=Fasle

Comment: "message" in data["data"] will output false only because data["data"] is a list and if you try 'message' in data["data"][0], you will get true.

Comment: Thanks!                                                                                                          so why this  line of code is working?                                                                          for post in data["data"]:

  print post["link"]

Comment: @DavidLerech what are you printing too, your error ( from the answer's comment) is coming from printing to like cmd. Where the output can't handle that character.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is working just fine for me, adding answer instead of comment because attaching screenshot.[image]

You might need to change encoding of the message, try this:

```
for post in data['data']"
    print post['message'].encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This is the error i get

C:\Users\david.lerech\Desktop>python fbrival.py
Name of competitor?slotomania
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fbrival.py", line 13, in <module>
    print post['message']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp862.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position
 165: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: edited the answer, please try changing encoding of your message as you have \u2019 etc in message which is not getting decoded.